# jQuery Datatables column sum() of hh:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, datatables, momentjs

I'm using jQuery Datatables and i need to make a sum of a time (hh:mm:ss) column.

I'm adding column data with sum() plugin (https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/api/sum%28%29.js), that i don't really get how it works.

```
        var time_api = this.api();
        //total
        var total = time_api.column(3)
                .data()
                .sum();           
            
        //footer
        $(time_api.column(3)
            .footer())
            .html(total);
```

This gives me this output which is a sum, but it needs some tweaks, and i **can't figure out how to turn this**:

[image]

Into this: **12:03:05** (the correct sum output).

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
"footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
    var api = this.api(), data;
    // Total over all pages
    total_ID = api.column(0).data().reduce( function (a, b) {
        return ~~a + ~~b;
    }, 0 );
    total_Duration = api.column(1).data().reduce( function (a, b) {
        return moment.duration(a).asMilliseconds() + moment.duration(b).asMilliseconds();
    }, 0 );
    // Total over this page
    pageTotal_ID = api.column(0, { page: 'current'} ).data().reduce( function (a, b) {
        return ~~a + ~~b;
    }, 0 );
    pageTotal_Duration = api.column(1, { page: 'current'} ).data().reduce( function (a, b) {
        return moment.duration(a).asMilliseconds() + moment.duration(b).asMilliseconds();
    }, 0 );
    // Update footer Column "quantita"
    $( api.column(0).footer()).html(
        pageTotal_ID + ' ('+ total_ID +' total)'
    );
    $( api.column(1).footer()).html(
        moment.utc(pageTotal_Duration).format("HH:mm:ss") + ' ('+ moment.utc(total_Duration).format("HH:mm:ss") + ' total)'
    );
}   
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add some description?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [plugin source](https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/api/sum%28%29.js), it first converts string cell content to a number, and then performs addition. You should extend handling of cell values by parsing your formatted values HH:MM:SS (e.g. by a regexp), then convert it to time interval in seconds (HH*24+MM*60+SS), then sum up these values, and then convert it back to hours/minutes/seconds.

You can update `sum` function like this:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'sum()', function ( ) {
    return this.flatten().reduce( function ( a, b ) {

        var timeRegexp = /^(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/

        var matches = a.match(timeRegexp);
        if (matches) {
            var hh = matches[1], mm = matches[2], ss = matches[3];
            var intervalAsSeconds = hh * 24 + mm * 60 + ss;
            return b + intervalAsSeconds;
        }

        if ( typeof a === 'string' ) {
            a = a.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') * 1;
        }
        if ( typeof b === 'string' ) {
            b = b.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') * 1;
        }

        return a + b;
    }, 0 );
} );
```

To convert sum in seconds back to HH:MM:SS you can use the following function:

```
function secondsToTime(seconds) {
  var hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
  var minutes = Math.floor((seconds % 3600) / 60); 
  var seconds = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
  return (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + 
         (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + 
         (seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
}
```

Some examples of back conversion:

```
console.log(secondsToTime(45)) // 00:00:45
console.log(secondsToTime(125)) // 00:02:05
console.log(secondsToTime(3600)) // 01:00:00
console.log(secondsToTime(3725)) // 01:02:05
```

Comment: So u say split the number into 11:62:65 and then create formulas to make output look like 12:03:05? U have any code snippet that could get me started? Thanks!

Comment: Answer is updated (conversions of cell values to seconds and back to HH:MM:SS are added).
This is plain javascript, and I believe you can also use some helper functions of moment.js (since you have mentioned it in tags) to handle intervals easier.

Comment: @Alexey The above code is throwing the error as 
TypeError: a.match is not a function. 
Any the solution?

Comment: @Steffi datatables api could change so `this.flatten()...` could return something else than collection Please check the type of that and type of `a` before calling .match() on it, it was expected to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is adapted to [Pranav C Balans 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435987/datejavascript-change-a-numeric-value-into-time-value) .

```
        var time_api= this.api();

        var total= tempo.column(3)
                .data()
                .sum();            
        total= total.toString();       
        while (total.length < 6){
           tempoTotal = "0" + tempoTotal   
        }    

        total= total.replace(/^(\d+)(\d{2})(\d{2})$/, function(m, m1, m2, m3) {
            m1 = Number(m1); // convert captured group value to number
            m2 = Number(m2);
            m2 += parseInt(m3 / 60, 10); // get minutes from second and add it to minute
            m3 = m3 % 60; // get soconds
            m1 += parseInt(m2 / 60, 10); // get minutes from minute and add it to hour
            m2 = m2 % 60; // get minutes
            // add 0 to minute and second if single digit , slice(-2) will select last 2 digit
            return m1 + ':' + ('0' + m2).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + m3).slice(-2); // return updated string
        })

        //write in footer
        $(tempo.column(3)
            .footer())
            .html(total);
```

Comment: If you don't want to add sum js and api() then its possible by javascript without api.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go little tricky in this kinda situation. Create a hidden column with `time` but just the `seconds`. Now I can use this column to calculate the `total` and convert it back to whatever the format I need.

```
    $('#tblTime').DataTable({
    "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {

        var api = this.api();

        //convert seconds to hour:minute:seconds
        var secondsToHms = function(d) {
          d = Number(d);
          var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
          var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
          var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

          return h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
        };

        //sum of hidden colunm hours in seconds
        var sum_hours_estimated = api
          .column( 2 ) //hidden column
          .data()
          .reduce( function (a, b) {
              return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        }, 0 );

        //covert the seconds into hour.minute
        var hours_estimated = secondsToHms(sum_hours_estimated);   

        var summary = '<ul><li>Total Time ' + hours_estimated + '</li><ul>';
        $(api.column(1).footer()).html(summary);
    },
    //hide the column
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [ 2 ],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
        }
    ]
});

//Use this if "columnDefs" doesn't work
$('#tblTime').DataTable().column( 2 ).visible( false );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the dsame problem and I found a solution that works for me:

```
footerCallback: function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api(), data;

        var intVal = function ( i ) {
            return i != null ? moment.duration(i).asSeconds() : 0;
        };

        var total = api.column( 3 ).data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
            var total = intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            var totalFormatted = [
                parseInt(total / 60 / 60),
                parseInt(total / 60 % 60),
                parseInt(total % 60)
            ].join(":").replace(/\b(\d)\b/g, "0$1");
            return totalFormatted;
        }, 0 );

        jQuery(api.column( 3 ).footer()).html(total);
    }
});
```