# datejavascript change a numeric value into time value

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

In JavaScript, jQuery, moment.js or any library,

how would u change a numeric value like **116265** (11 hours, 62 minutes, 65 seconds)

into the correct time value **12:03:05** ?

**Edit/Update:**

It must work also if the hours are bigger then 2 digits. (In my case the hours are the only part that can be bigger then 2 digits.)

Comment: how about limiting date input to date instead??  Anyway values over 60 should be disallowed when it comes to hours and minutes

Comment: why is that number: 116265? shouldn't it be like: 120305? if your are getting these sort of strings, you will need to modulo it until it is correct, then split it up in in hours, minutes and second portions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method with function

```js
console.log(
  '116265'.replace(/^(\d+)(\d{2})(\d{2})$/, function(m, m1, m2, m3) {
    m1 = Number(m1); // convert captured group value to number
    m2 = Number(m2);
    m2 = Number(m2);
    m2 += parseInt(m3 / 60, 10); // get minutes from second and add it to minute
    m3 = m3 % 60; // get soconds
    m1 += parseInt(m2 / 60, 10); // get minutes from minute and add it to hour
    m2 = m2 % 60; // get minutes
    // add 0 to minute and second if single digit , slice(-2) will select last 2 digit
    return m1 + ':' + ('0' + m2).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + m3).slice(-2); // return updated string
  })
)
```

Comment: I would suggest to revert the String first, in order to get 2 digit for seconds, 2 digit for mins, and the rest for hours(he mentioned that hour would be bigger than two digits).

Comment: @PranavCBalan This is brilliant! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Cris : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var a = '116265'.replace(/^(\d+)(\d{2})(\d{2})$/, '$1:$2:$3')
var hms = a; // your input string
var a = hms.split(':'); // split it at the colons
if (a[2] >= 60) {
  a[2] -= 60, a[1] ++;
}
if (a[1] >= 60) {
  a[1] -= 60, a[0] ++;
}
console.log(a[0] + ":" + ("0" + a[1]).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + a[2]).slice(-2));
```